# Error in gdata::installXLSXsupport() on Docker Centos 7

Tags: r, perl, docker, centos7, gdata

I try to install gdata package with XLSX support on Centos7 in Docker image. Running command *gdata::installXLSXsupport()* fails.

My Dockerfile looks as follows:

```
FROM centos:latest

RUN yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
RUN yum install -y R
RUN yum install -y libcurl-devel
RUN yum install -y openssl-devel
RUN yum install -y libssh2-devel
RUN yum install -y libxml2-devel


RUN yum install -y perl-CPAN
RUN R -e "install.packages('gdata', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "gdata::installXLSXsupport()"
```

Build process crashes at the last step with message:

```
Step 10/10 : RUN R -e "gdata::installXLSXsupport()"
 ---> Running in 4e15bdcd2422

R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06) -- "Another Canoe"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> gdata::installXLSXsupport()
Attempting to create directory /root/perl5
Warning: prerequisite Test::More 0 not found.
Tried to deactivate inactive local::lib '/root/perl5'
Use of uninitialized value $deactivating in numeric eq (==) at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/local/lib.pm line 381.
Use of uninitialized value $deactivating in numeric eq (==) at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/local/lib.pm line 383.
Use of uninitialized value $options{"interpolate"} in numeric eq (==) at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/local/lib.pm line 424.
Use of uninitialized value $options{"interpolate"} in numeric eq (==) at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/local/lib.pm line 424.
Use of uninitialized value $options{"interpolate"} in numeric eq (==) at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/local/lib.pm line 424.
Use of uninitialized value $_[0] in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/File/Basename.pm line 341.
fileparse(): need a valid pathname at /usr/share/perl5/CPAN/FirstTime.pm line 1354.
Error in gdata::installXLSXsupport() :
Unable to install Perl XLSX support libraries.

In addition: Warning message:
running command ''/usr/bin/perl' '/usr/lib64/R/library/gdata/perl/install_modules.pl'' had status 255
Execution halted
The command '/bin/sh -c R -e "gdata::installXLSXsupport()"' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What may be the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

gdata::installXLSXsupport() --

> This function calls the perl script 'install_modules.pl' located in
>   the perl subdirectory of the gdata package directory (or inst/perl in
>   the source package). This perl script attempts to use the perl 'CPAN'
>   package, which should be included as part of most perl installations,
>   to automatically download, compile, and install the
>   Compress::Raw::Zlib and Spreadsheet::XLSX perl modules needed for
>   read.xls

Sometimes it's too much pain to use CPAN.

Try to replace `RUN R -e "gdata::installXLSXsupport()"` with

`yum install -y perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib perl-Spreadsheet-XLSX`

Comment: Thanks. unfortunately it do not work (the message when gdata is loaded is still shown). What is strange as, as you quoted, documentation says this is what this function is doing. I've tried to install it before installing package (so that maybe it will be used somehow in the package installation process), but it doesn't work too. However, when this is installed, the error returned by "RUN R -e "gdata::installXLSXsupport()", changed to "Error in gdata::installXLSXsupport() :
Unable to install Perl XLSX support libraries.

Execution halted".